# INDIRECT with name of fixed values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is it possible to to use `INDIRECT` with a `Name` with a fixed value?

If the `Name` is a range, then it works fine, however I guess it would better if it contains fixed list values (for performance reasons).

For example in the sheet:

[image]

`C5` has a Data Validation formula as `=INDIRECT($B$5)`

[image]

If `AB` Name is used (which is based on fixed values) the `C5` doesn't show expected values, but if `ABx` is used (which is based on range), then `C5` shows the values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel's INDIRECT function simply doesn't work with dynamic ranges, this link may be of use to you,

http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/xl-indirect.htm

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.